# Modify Python sorted() build-in func to return a list with values from lambda

Tags: python

Given a python list:

```
nums = [9,4,5,7,-1,2,-3,0]
```

The task is to write a function that will return a new list with squares of numbers of original list in ascending order.
Expected output:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 49, 81]
```

The simplest way to do this is just create a new list and then apply Python build-in sorted() function:

```
def my_sort(nums):
    new_list = [i**2 for i in nums]
    return sorted(new_list)

print(my_sort(nums))
```

output as expected:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 49, 81]
```

However there is another option is to use "key" argument and pass lambda function inside sorted():

```
new_list = sorted(nums, key=lambda x: x**2)
print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[0, -1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
```

Here we have the same sorting behavior with difference that sorted() function return sorted list with *original* values.

My question - **is there any way to override python build-in sorted() function that it will return a sored list with values from lambda?**

**UPD:**

Apparently i have to explain a little where this question came from, for greater clarity. I had a python interview where this question was asked. When i implemented my basic solution, the interviewer said that in terms of big O() complexity, this solution is not entirely effective, arguing that fisrt we create a new array\list at the beginning and only then apply sorting algorithm over it and suggested writing sorting "on the fly". I was confused because believed that there was no point in writing a custom sorting algorithm and no doubt it will perform slower than the built-in solution, i woud never write my own "Timesort" algorithm (which as i kwon implemented in sorted()). Later, thinking about this question, there was a suggestion that a solution with sorting via a key would perform faster than sorting with the preliminary creation of a new list. Therefore, this question arose. However, further tests showed that soution when we create a new list works faster than sorting through the key=lambda function. But of course, this is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I don't think it was created in this scope, you should better use a list comprehension as you did above and then call sorted over the list. What you did in the second example is to sort them according to their square, so that -1 has a bigger square than 0.

Comment: For some things one should not just ask "is this possible", but also "is this wise".

Comment: no, and also why

Comment: The job of `sorted` is to produce a new ordering of the original values; that’s it. If you want a wrapper that sorts a new list, fine; but do not subvert the expectations of anyone reading your code by making `sorted` do something unexpected. (And by “anyone”, I’m including you in two months.)

Comment: But why? Your solution is already very reasonable

Comment: First of all, thanks all for the feedback. This question has less practical application, more "academic" curiosity.

Comment: The interviewer was talking total nonsense. The complexity of the sort (usually expected to be O(x log x)) will always dominate about the time needed for the squaring (expected to be O(x)), whether you do it in a separate step or integrated with the sorting. That's the whole point of asymptotic complexity.

Answer (score 38):

> is there any way to override python build-in sorted() function that it will return a sored list with values from lambda?

Sorry, but this is the WrongWayToIt™.  It fights how the tools were designed to be used.  Instead, the right way is to convert the data first and then sort it:

```
>>> nums = [9,4,5,7,-1,2,-3,0]
>>> sorted(map(lambda x: x**2, nums))
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 49, 81]
```

If for some reason you still have to rewrite *sorted()*, follow essentially same pattern in the new function:

```
>>> def new_sorted(data, key):
...     return sorted(map(key, data))
...

>>> new_sorted(nums, key=lambda x: x*x)
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 49, 81]
```

Comment: question: Why use a lambda and not `sorted((x**2 for x in nums))`?

Comment: @GorttheRobot The OP specifically asked for a *lambda* example.  That was reasonable because his goal was to write a variant of *sorted()* where the key-function was passed in as a parameter.  In that case, a list comprehension in the final code wouldn't make as much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have got it all wrong. That's not how the `key` parameter is supposed to work. The value of the key parameter should be a function (or other callable) that takes a single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes.

That's why you are getting the *original values*.

See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.12/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score -3):

You can do it by importing builtins module to use original sorted method and write your own in current scope

```py
import builtins
def sorted(l,/, *, key=None, reverse=False, f=None):
    bsorted = builtins.sorted
    if f is None:
        return bsorted(l, key=key, reverse=reverse)
    else:
        l = [f(x) for x in l]
    return bsorted(l, key=key, reverse=reverse)
```

However you are overwriting a well-known builtin method to add new functionality, which could cause confusion when other people read your code. You should better use another name instead of doing it.

Comment: Personally I couldn't agree more that this is likely to cause confusion

Comment: By doing this you are effectively breaking the language. Please don’t.

Comment: The OP has a solution to what they are actually trying to do, but apparently doesn't like the resulting code.   You are suggesting making the language work in unexpected ways for all users of the OP's codebase, justl to make a couple lines of clear, understandble python code look more like OP wants them to look.   That is not a good idea.

Comment: @GorttheRobot Right so I also said the OP should better use another name instead of overwriting the builtin function. In addition OP comments that he asked for curiosity but not practical reason, so I think the answer is just to show a possibility to do such thing but of course not the recommended way to solve the problem.

Answer (score -3):

You can replace the original `sorted` function globally by setting `builtins.sorted`. `my_own_sorted` is your own implementation.

```
import builtins
builtins.sorted = my_own_sorted
```

Comment: You could do that. However, it risks breaking any library you import that uses sorted.

Comment: Simply answering the OP‘s question. We cannot deny them making their own experiences.

Comment: People are free to make their own mistakes but we can at least warn them :D.  (p.s I didn't down vote)